# Emberjs create new model after saving

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This seems extremely trivial and I feel awkward asking but I can't seem to create a fresh model after saving the current.

Think todo app, where you want to keep adding new tasks:

I have a very simple route which saves correctly, but doesn't update the frontend with a new model

```
  model() {
    return RSVP.hash({
      distro: get(this, 'store').createRecord('distro'),
    });
  },

  setupController(controller, models) {
    controller.setProperties(models);
  },

  actions: {
    saveDistro(distro) {
      let newDistro = get(this, 'store').createRecord('distro');

      distro.save().then(() => {
        set(this, 'distro', newDistro);
      });
    },
  }
```

I think I'm just missing the obvious here?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "can't seem to create"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating 2 different `distros` here. The first one is what is passed to your controller to be displayed, and the second is the one that is created in the action `saveDistro()`.

Generally, you don't want to create a new record in the `model()` hook. That is intended for finding data. Since I'm not sure what you're doing in your controller and view with the first distro, I can't comment on that, but I'd recommend something like this:

EDIT:

```
// Controller
init() {
  this._super(...arguments)
  this.set('formAttrs', {
    attr1: null,
    attr2: null
    // ...
  })
},

actions: {
  saveDistro() {
    const attrs = this.get('formAttrs')
    this.send('saveDistro', attrs)
  }
}

// Model
actions: {
  saveDistro(attrs) {
    let newDistro = get(this, 'store').createRecord('distro', attrs);

    distro.save().then(() => {
      // transition to new distro route
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it's a simple "create new" route so I don't think I want to be fetching all current distros do I? But I need a model for the form to save data in, hence creating it on the model hook

Comment: gotcha. You don't need a model to build the form to save the data. In fact I'd urge you not to do that. Instead, in your controller, create a form attrs object to hold the values, and then use the values to create the new `distro` in the action

Comment: I've updated answer to reflect what I'm talking about

Comment: Ah that's interesting, I've been mucking with ember for awhile and I always avoid controllers completely as people keep saying their bad and going away soon...

Comment: You could do the same with a component instead of a controller. That's what I do.